# Publishing a .net core 6.0.100-preview.4.21255.9 api app to Azure App service

Tags: azure, api, asp.net-core-6.0

I am attempting to publish a net core 6.0.100-preview.4.21255.9 api app to Azure App service.
The application publishes correctly from VS2019 as a self contained deployment. When hitting the url of the app service i get HTTP Error 500.32 - ANCM Failed to Load dll. I expect the swagger to come up.

If I create a web app with net core 6.0.100-preview.4.21255.9 and deploy that it works fine.

Any ideas on how do get this to work on azure app service?

Comment: what do you means I create web app with .net core 6.0.100 then it is working fine. Both are at Azure of Different env. what exact error you get ?

Comment: The error is HTTP Error 500.32 - ANCM Failed to Load dll

Comment: When I create a blank api app and publish it I get the error but when I create a web app and publish it works. Both are using net core 6.0.100-preview.4.21255.9. The api app and web app I created to test with are blank apps create with VS 2019.

Comment: There are advanced tool. The error page you show , it has link and it redirect to some page in Azure portal and there is kudu console. This will give you more insight of that. I suspect that it has issue IIS integration.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this was my mistake. The API is working just fine.